# ConfigFactory ParseFile resolve with Variable Substitution with a Java system property

Tags: java, scala, configuration, typesafe, hocon

I am having issues trying to use the variable substitution with the typesafehub ConfigFactory fileParser

my code is

```
Configuration(ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("/Users/TDong/files/app.conf")).resolve())
```

and my app.conf file contains

```
path = ${java.home}
```

on every resolve I cannot resolve that variable with variable substitution to find the java system property home. Any ideas how to make this work

Answer (score 2):

To get advantage of the overriding features you need to stick with `ConfigFactory.load()` or deal yourself with [merging configuration](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#merging-config-trees) through the `Config#withFallback` method. In fact this is how 
`ConfigFactory#load()` works.

https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior

> The convenience method ConfigFactory.load() loads the following
>   (first-listed are higher priority):
>
> - system properties application.conf (all resources on classpath with
>     this name)
> - application.json (all resources on classpath with this
>     name)
> - application.properties (all resources on classpath with this
>     name)
> - reference.conf (all resources on classpath with this name)

IMHO you should rely on the default behaviour and use `-Dconfig.file=/path/to/your.conf` to pass files as arguments to your application.

I highly recommed to go through the documentation that is very well written.

Answer (score 1):

At `path = ${java.home}` you are referring to other value under `java.home` in the same configuration file. In order to override value you should run your application with

`java -jar -Djava.home=VALUE your_jar.jar`

or using some tool that allows you to pass arguments.

If you want to set this value by `System.setProperty()` than you need to set it up before loading configuration file.